# sed:can't read /usr/lib/libltdl.a:No such file or directory

Tags: linux, make

I tried to install the package [libgraph](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/libgraph/) but while executing `make` it says that

```
justin@justin-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC ~/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1 $ make
Makefile:781: warning: overriding commands for target `libgraph.pc'
Makefile:333: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libgraph.pc'
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1'
Makefile:781: warning: overriding commands for target `libgraph.pc'
Makefile:333: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libgraph.pc'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc/man'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1'
Makefile:781: warning: overriding commands for target `libgraph.pc'
Makefile:333: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libgraph.pc'
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=link gcc  -DFONTDIR=\""/usr/local/share/libgraph/Font/"\"   -o libguile-libgraph.la -rpath /usr/local/lib -version-info 0:2:0 -export-dynamic -lguile -lguile-ltdl -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lcrypt -lm -ldl   guile-libgraph.lo -lgraph -lm -lSDL_image -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL 
grep: /usr/lib/libltdl.la: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /usr/lib/libltdl.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libltdl.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [libguile-libgraph.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/justin/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please specify your OS/distribution. Please don't use screenshots for text. Just paste the text. Also, isn't libgraph available as a binary package for your distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I got how to fix the error.The steps you have to do rectify the error is:

1. Uninstall the package `libtool`
2. install `libtool` as given in [libtool](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/building_shared_libraries_once_using_autotools)(Files for libtool would be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
3. *search* for **libltd** using the search bar in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and you would get 5 files:`libltdl.a`(package),`libltdl.a`(script file),`libltdl.so`,`libltdl.so.7`,`libltdl.so.7.3.0`.
4. Copy these 5 files into `/usr/lib/`.
5. You're done and after executing `make` they wouldn't be the error:`libltdl.a is not a valid libtool archive`.

**N.B**:Here I have tried this on Linux Mint 16 64 bit MATE edition.I'm not sure about other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently need some extra development libraries installed to build `libgraph`; those should have been mentioned in the `INSTALL` or `README` file included with the sources.

On my Debian system I'd need to install `libltdl-dev` to fix the problems you show, however after that other development libraries may also be needed (the compilation stops after the first error, so you don't see all requirements when something goes wrong).

That said, I'd just install Debian's version of `libgraph` as a package, like Faheem Mitha suggested.

EDIT: The current version of `libgraph` for Debian is packaged as `libgraph4`:

```
$ apt-cache show libgraph4
Package: libgraph4
Source: graphviz
Version: 2.26.3-14+deb7u2
Installed-Size: 146
Maintainer: David Claughton <dave@eclecticdave.com>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libcdt4, libltdl7 (>= 2.4.2)
Conflicts: libgraphviz4
Description-en: rich set of graph drawing tools - graph library
 Graphviz is a set of graph drawing tools. See the description of the graphviz
 package for a full description.
 .
```

This package contains the graph library.

Comment: :But I can't see any debian file for `libgraph`.Could you show me a link that has a debian file for `libgraph`.

Comment: @justin: install the libltdl-dev package, then it should work.

Comment: I've added details of Debian's `libgraph4` which is what you're looking for IMHO.

Comment: @ott:Sorry to say but I still gives the same error as mentioned before.Just note that I'm using linux mint 16 and I think `libtdl7` comes with it so you might have to either uninstall `libtdl7` or install `libtdl7-dev` isn't it?.But so far I couldn't get the `libtdl7-dev` file and can't uninstall `libtdl7` because programs like vlc etc depends on it.Could you suggest any other options.

Comment: @wurtel:As you said I have installed the package `libgraph4` but could you tell me whether by this package you could use the `graphics.h` library in a C program.That's why I was trying to install the `libgraph` package.

Comment: You need to remember that if you want to do development, you need the `-dev` version of the library package as well. Usually that version is simply `libname-dev`, i.e. remove any version number and add `-dev`. However it appears that in this case the development package is called `libgraphviz-dev`; at least on Debian it is. So you also need to install that.

Comment: @wurtel:Could you tell me the options that should be specified after `gcc` to compile the file with `graphics.h`.

Comment: You can see what files are contained in an installed package with e.g. `dpkg -l libgraphviz-dev`, so you can see it contains `/usr/include/graphviz/graph.h`. Hence you need either `-I/usr/include/graphviz` or `#include <graphviz/graph.h>` in your program source; but these are things any C developer should know; perhaps you've bitten off more than you can chew. This goes beyond the scope of the original question though.